# How to Suppress "Using bos_token, but it is not set yet..." in HuggingFace T5 Tokenizer

Tags: pytorch, huggingface-tokenizers

I'd like to turn off the warning that huggingface is generating when I use *unique_no_split_tokens*

```
In[2]   tokenizer = T5Tokenizer.from_pretrained("t5-base")
In[3]   tokenizer(" ".join([f"<extra_id_{n}>" for n in range(1,101)]), return_tensors="pt").input_ids.size()
Out[3]: torch.Size([1, 100])
    Using bos_token, but it is not set yet.
    Using cls_token, but it is not set yet.
    Using mask_token, but it is not set yet.
    Using sep_token, but it is not set yet.
```

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: if you want so add standard special tokens see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73322462/how-to-add-all-standard-special-tokens-to-my-hugging-face-tokenizer-and-model?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution worked for me:

```
tokenizer.add_tokens([f"_{n}" for n in range(1,100)], special_tokens=True)
model.resize_token_embeddings(len(tokenizer))
tokenizer.save_pretrained('pathToExtendedTokenizer/')
tokenizer = T5Tokenizer.from_pretrained("pathToExtendedTokenizer/")
```

Comment: I don't get it, why are you adding random tokens labeled `_{n}`?

Comment: the default seems to be a different string for the extra ids: `tokenizer.all_special_tokens=['</s>', '<unk>', '<pad>', '<extra_id_0>', '<extra_id_1>', '<extra_id_2>', '<extra_id_3>', '<extra_id_4>', '<extra_id_5>', '<extra_id_6>', '<extra_id_7>', '<extra_id_8>', '<extra_id_9>', '<extra_id_10>', '<extra_id_11>', '<extra_id_12>', '<extra_id_13>', '<extra_id_14>', '<extra_id_15>', '<extra_id_16>', '<extra_id_17>', '<extra_id_18>', '<extra_id_19>', '<extra_id_20>', '<extra_id_21>', ...] 
`

Comment: why not `    tokenizer.add_tokens([f"<extra_id_{n}>" for n in range(1, 100)], special_tokens=True)
`

Comment: why do you say this worked for you? This did not work for me. What is work for you? Can you paste the output of your script?

Comment: generating/parsing sequences with units _xy  was  more convenient for my application (where x,y are elements on [1,2,...,9]), e.g. _23 _56 ...